# I'm trying to get make text float around an image but it's not working

Tags: image, css-float, alignment, floating

After the first line of text the second line of text goes to the bottom of image and i don't know why! help? Here is my coding:

```
< div style="border-radius:5px; border: 1px solid #E6DFDF; color:black; margin: 3px; margin-top: 3px; padding: 3px; min-height:20px; background-color: #8bc5c0; -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px 1px #333; -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px 1px #333;box-shadow:1px 1px 2px 1px #333;" >
< img src="{AskerPortraitURL-30}" width="30" align="left" style="margin-right:3px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #E6DFDF; border-radius: 3px;"/>< askky >{Asker} asked:< /askky > {Question}< br >< /div >
```

Answer (score 0):

You are all set. Only give `disply: inline-block;` and define its `width: 30%;` or whatever you want. Now it would behave as an inline element for others but block for itself. Hope this works.